# Custom upload function for PrimeNG

Tags: angular, file-upload, primeng

I have an angular form backed with PrimeNG UI framework. I removed the Upload button because i need the whole upload logic only trigger when "Upload Progress" button is hit. How can i still reference the file variable? When onSubmitProgress() is triggered, the file name is blank

Screen
[image]
TS

```
  onAttachmentSelected(event: any) {
    this.uploadedFiles = event.files;
    console.log('selected attachment file:', this.uploadedFiles[0].name)
  }
  onAttachmentHandled(event) {
    console.log('handing the file ')
  }
  onSubmitProgress() {
    // upload file
    console.log('submit attachment file:', this.uploadedFiles)
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-3">
  <p-fileUpload name="x" [customUpload]="true" 
 [showUploadButton]="false" (onSelect)="onAttachmentSelected($event)" (uploadHandler)="onAttachmentHandled($event)"
 [maxFileSize]="5000000"></p-fileUpload>
</div>

<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-3">
  <button pButton label="Update Progress" (click)="onSubmitProgress()"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<p-fileUpload name="uploadAvatar"
              [customUpload]="true"
              (uploadHandler)="onFileUploadClicked($event)"
              (onSelect)="onSelectFile($event)"
              accept="image/*"
              [maxFileSize]="500000">
</p-fileUpload>
```

TS

```
onFileUploadClicked(event: {files: Blob[]}) {
   doSomthingWithFile(event.files[0]);
}

onSelectFile(event: {files: FormData[]}) {
    this.uploadedFiles = event.files;
}
```

Comment: i dont quite get 'uploadHandler', as my upload only trigger when submit button is hit. I have updated my question, after reference the code above it still doesn't work

Comment: That's why I put Select also (to use an external button if you want). 
You can keep the files in your component when selected and when `submit` you already have them as `this.uploadedFiles`.